# How do i add an image in Java?

Tags: java, image, swing

```
frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Sam/Pictures/DesktopBackgrounds/image.png")));
```

I saw this on another question so i tried to use it and the class runs with no errors however no image is on the screen.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

class FullSceenToggleAction extends AbstractAction {

    private JFrame frame;
    private GraphicsDevice fullscreenDevice;

    public FullSceenToggleAction(JFrame frame) {
        this(frame, GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice());
    }

    public FullSceenToggleAction(JFrame frame, GraphicsDevice fullscreenDevice) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.fullscreenDevice = fullscreenDevice;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.dispose();
        if (frame.isUndecorated()) {
            fullscreenDevice.setFullScreenWindow(null);
            frame.setUndecorated(false);
        } else {
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            fullscreenDevice.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
        }
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.repaint();
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static final void addKeyBinding(JComponent c, String key, final Action action) {
        c.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key), key);
        c.getActionMap().put(key, action);
        c.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fullscreen Toggle Test");
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(new JLabel("Hey"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(960, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("Virtual World");
        frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Sam/Pictures/DesktopBackgrounds/image.png")));
        addKeyBinding(frame.getRootPane(), "F11", new FullSceenToggleAction(frame));
    }

}
```

In case you need it this is the full code.

Comment: Lots of issues there, but first and foremost, you should always call `setVisible(true)` **after** adding all components/images.

Comment: But other issues -- better to get Images first via `ImageIO.read(...)`, better to get them as resources not files (look this up for more on this). You seem to be trying to add two JLabels to the same BorderLayout.CENTER position in your GUI, one stating "Hey", the other with the image, which would completely displace the first one.

Comment: I moved `frame.setVisible(true);` under `frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Sam/Pictures/DesktopBackgrounds/image.png")));` now I don't see "Hey" but I can see the image

Comment: And you don't see "hey" for the very reason I noted above -- you're displacing the "hey" JLabel with the image label since they're both being added to the same contentPane BorderLayout.CENTER. You will want to read up on the layout managers and how they work.

Comment: Do you know where I can find information on the "layout managers"?

Comment: Sure, Google [Java Swing Layout Managers](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20swing%20layout%20managers). Very first hit.

Comment: I now added them both to different ContentPanes with different BorderLayout however no change all I see is the image `Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
  contentPane.add(new JLabel("Hey"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
  Container contentPane2 = frame.getContentPane();
  contentPane2.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/SamBr/Pictures/DesktopBackgrounds/image.png")), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);`

Comment: You are confusing object and variable -- a very basic and key distinction in Java. Yes, your code above has two different Container variables, contentPane and contentPane2, but note that they both reference the **very same object**. So you are in fact adding your two JLabels to the very same contentPane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with your codes. In Swing, the order of your codes does makes a difference.

**Code order issue:**

Currently you are adding an image to the frame ***after*** you set the size. When the frame size changes, the paint manager will be consulted to repaint the frame. Hence you will only be able to see the `"Hey"` label you added earlier but not the image.

It is advisable to set the size after you added all the components you need. If not, you may want to `revalidate()` your frame later.

---

I will usually setup the components in the following order:

```
// Create frame
// Set default close operation for frame
// Add components or container to frame
// pack the frame   (frame will be repainted by this action)
// set visible as true
```

---

**Layout issue:**

You are using the frame's default layout (BorderLayout). If you do not state the position/direction for the components to be added in BorderLayout, it will be added to the CENTER by BorderLayout's default.

In your codes, you added the image (2nd label) without stating the position (String specification). Doing so will replace the first label with the second label. Hence only one component will be shown in the frame.

---

**Other issues:**

There are some other issues which I would summarize below:

- It is advisable to `setVisible(true)` last to prevent flickering issues.
- I would prefer to add another container such as JPanel into the JFrame and add the components in the panel instead of adding directly to the frame.
- With the above, you can `pack()` the frame which allows it to determine its own preferredSize according to the added components.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding imageIcon Label to content pane works.

```
    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(new JLabel("Hey"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    contentPane.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Sam/Pictures/DesktopBackgrounds/image.png")));
```

Comment: You do know of course from the [JFrame API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) that `"As a convenience, the add, remove, and setLayout methods of this class are overridden, so that they delegate calls to the corresponding methods of the ContentPane."` In other words the API answers my specific question above -- there is no difference, and so your answer won't solve his problem. Period.

Comment: as user3437460 said sequence and as you said about LayoutManager, both are correct. and above code of mine is tested and it works fine too.

Answer (score -2):

you may find the code helpful.I posted this code for understanding purpose.

```
public class AddingIconJLabel {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("JLabel Test");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Sam/Pictures/DesktopBackgrounds/image.png");
    JLabel label = new JLabel(imageIcon);    
    frame.add(label);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

this will output the following..Hope you found my help useful.

[image: output]